# PHP: How do I test for whitespace at the beginning and end of a string?

Tags: php

How do I test for whitespace at the beginning and end of a string?

I don't want to remove spaces, I just want a boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE` returned if they exist.

Thanks.

Comment: http://ideone.com/A6cork

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = <your string>;
$ns_string = trim($string);
$spaces_present = ($ns_string == $string) ? false : true;
```

in shorter notation

```
$space_present = ($string != trim($string));
```

Comment: More direct and simple solution and it covers check for both start and end of the string.

Comment: Or shorter: `$space_present = ($string != trim($string));`

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "test";

    if($str[0] == " "|| $str[strlen($str)-1] == " ")
        echo "space at the start or the end";

?>
```

Comment: I think this is the most simple solution.

Comment: @sємsєм Yep! I wanted to keep it simple so you can easy understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Check like this

```
  if (substr($str, -1) == " " || $str[0] == " " ) {

    }
```

Comment: at the start and/or the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
ctype_space($str[0]) || ctype_space(substr($str, -1))
```

Comment: This one is probably the best - using dedicated ctype_* function and substr with -1 without getting strlen.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$test = 'test ';

if (strpos($test, ' ') === 0 || strpos($test, ' ') === strlen($test)-1) {
    return true;
}
?>
```

EDIT: See darkbees explaination

Comment: It should be `===` here

Comment: From php.net : Warning: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. With other words if the `$string` does not contain any spaces it will return `false` but in PHP `false==0` will return true

Answer (score 0):

simple regex

```
preg_match("~(^\s|\s$)~", $subject);
```

Comment: regex for this seems bit overkill to me

Comment: @DarkBee This is the kind of thing regex is made for, though.

Comment: regex = now you have two problems